# Loading index.html from assets into WebView but other files referenced in index.html can't be found

Tags: android, webview

### Problem

I am able to successfully load my `index.html` file in my `WebView` from the local `assets` directory with `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html);`

The page remains white and I get `js` errors in my chrome debug console that say that the `*.js` and `*.css` files that are linked in the `index.html` are not able to be found.  `Filed to load resource: net:: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

### Information

WebView settings

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

WebView also has a custom WebChromeClient and WebViewClient.

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
       ...
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
       ...
    </head>

    <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
      ...
      <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"> 
 </script>
      ...
    </body>

    </html>
```

I have a `www` directory inside my `assets` directory that contains my website content.

Directory Structure:

- assets

  - www

    - index.html
    - *.js (many js files)
    - styles.css
    - etc

All the files are located in the same directory as the `index.html` so I'm not sure why they aren't able to be found.

Is there something with the Android WebView that is causing this error?  I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue once. I have added the complete paths and it worked. Please add the path,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
       ...
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/www/styles.css">
       ...
    </head>

    <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
      ...
      <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/runtime.js"> 
 </script>
      ...
    </body>

    </html>
```

and respectively to all other files.

Comment: Also, try the same on a different device as it may be a device specific issue. Let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: It appears that this worked for the issues in the index.html file.  I'm now getting the same error for files linked inside the newly loaded file.  This is an interesting lead.

Comment: You might need to add the paths for same.  If not the. Try ../ this. It will work for sure.

Comment: Sadly, the other .js files are all obfuscated and I can't go through them all and prepend the full path to every link.

Comment: As per my knowledge on webviews there is no other way than finding and adding paths. :(  But still if you found any do let me know. Hey please don't forget to vote and accept :)

Comment: Well, I'll accept this answer because it does contain a solution to the initial problem.  I suppose I can reword this and ask again if need be.  Thanks!